# Center aligning two elements wrapped in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I'm trying to center a div that contains two elements. Usually what I'd do is set a width then use `margin: 0 auto;` but in this case, that doesn't apply because I don't know the combined width of both the textbox and submit button (horizontally adjacent) with all the padding and margins and what not.

So basically I have in pseudo-html:

```
<div class="search">
    <input id="query"><button id="searchSubmit">
</div>
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Not working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6B9DT/

Thanks!

Comment: Try recreating the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/, then paste the link into your question. It's hard to help without seeing more.

Comment: You can try to set the div display to `inline-block` (or `inline` for older browsers) and then set `text-align:center` to his container. But as Mike said, it's hard to help without an example.

Comment: body
    {
        text-align:center;
    } add this to your css, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `text-align: center;` is usefull in such cases...here is a  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/C3eZd/2/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="search">
    <input id="query"> 
    <button id="searchSubmit">Search</button>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
    text-align: center;
}
#search {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    /* for ie6/7: */
    *display: inline;

}
```

**Please note** that here `text-align: center;` has been given on `body` tag, it can be given to any `parent wrapper` of this `search` markup.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `display:block` for the search div :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this saves time 
Hope this helps

```
body
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/6B9DT/1/